# Verifying DKIM for AWS SES when can't add CNAME to root domain

Tags: amazon-ses

Up until recently, we were verifying domains for AWS SES DKIM by adding CNAMES to the root domain as per the AWS instructions.

Our DNS provider now no longer allows CNAMES to be added to the root domain (e.g. example.com) so we can't use this to verify DKIM for email addresses we typically use (which are generally in the format something@example.com).

Are there any other ways to verify domains for DKIM for SES without adding CNAMES to the root domain?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-domain-procedure.html